# Creating buffers that will not overlap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer, intersection, overlapping-features

I am dealing with a .shp with a number of points in it. The distances between points range from ~300m to 5km.

I wish to create a 1 km buffer around each point with as little overlap as possible. Each buffer should have an ID. Where 1km buffers overlap with each other, I would like to give that buffer a different ID.

So lets say I have 50 points, and I create a 1 km buffer around every point. Owing to the short distances between my points in the Shapefile, overlapping between buffers are inevitable. Where there is overlap, I would like to give one of those buffers a particular ID. I would like to replicate this throughout my entire dataset until there are no buffers of the same ID overlapping.

I am sure this is possible in QGIS with a combination of the vector manipulation tools, I am just struggling on the best approach.

I am using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour.

[image: My problem is exhibited on the left image. The resolution is on the right image. Not how the ID of the buffer has changed to prevent overlapping of the same ID]

Comment: Im not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to find the maximum buffer radius without overlapping?

Comment: No, each buffer MUST be at 1km. I want a 1 km buffer around each point in my shapefile. Where the buffers overlap, I would like to give them different IDs so that no buffer overlaps with another buffer of the same ID. Apologies, I have been recycling this in my head for some time so I may have failed to express myself clearly. I will knock up and upload some pictures that should hopefully better explain my problem!

Comment: Why dont you locate points that are closer than 1km, extract them from your dataset, and do buffer on those that left?

Comment: If I do that then I will have the same problem with my extracted dataset. I will still have points within 1km of each other. I could extract one half of the points and create a buffer around the existing points, and then replicate this with my extracted dataset. This would work although I'm aiming to find something a little more streamlined!

Comment: Maybe you will need to build a python script that loop over each buffer, if it instersect, test if the intersected buffer ID = ID2, if not, assign ID2 to the buffer, else, assign ID1

Comment: Yeah, this is where I fall short. I am used to using the majority of click tools in QGIS but I have no experience with scripting language. I could not create this kind of script myself, if i were provided with one and given some guidance I'm sure I could execute it though..

Comment: You could create your buffers - and then create Voronoi (Theissen) polygons.  If you clip each buffer polygon with its Voronoi polygon, you should get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would Intersect the buffers, turning the overlap into polygons.
Apply a  Spatial Join from the original Points to assign the original ID, clear the ID's that don't have a match.
 Join the two layers on the ID to compare Area. The buffers that overlapped have buffer.area > intersect.area.

Comment: Intersect seems like the quickest way to me.